# RequireJS loading leaf modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I'm new to RequireJS but seem to be hitting a brick wall.

The trouble starts with my "app" module. I'm not sure how to tell RequireJS to load my leaf modules - packages that depend on "app".

I think I understand why - since nothing in the system depends on them and they aren't registered anywhere, but I need to deal with this case.

How can I let RequireJS know about these modules and to load them appropriately?

Cheers

```
//index.html
....
<script data-main="app/config" src="/assets/js/libs/require.js"></script>
....

//config.js
require.config({
    deps: [ "app" ],
    paths: {
        libs: "../assets/js/libs",
        plugins: "../assets/js/plugins",
        jquery: "../assets/js/libs/jquery",
        underscore: "../assets/js/libs/underscore",
        backbone: "../assets/js/libs/backbone",
        marionette: "../assets/js/libs/backbone.marionette"
    }
});

//app.js
require(
    [ "jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette" ],
    function ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette ) {
        //....
    }
);

//app.view.js
require(
    [ "jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette", "app" ], 
    function ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette, App ) {
        //....
    }
);

//app.route.js 
require(
    [ "backbone", "app" ], 
    function ( Backbone, App ) {
        //....
    }
);
```

Hence:

- app.js depends on "jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette"
- app.view.js depends on "jquery", "underscore", "backbone",
- "marionette", "app" app.route.js depends on "backbone", "app"

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the docs ->
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config
dependencies are defined in the deps array. They are the first thing that's loaded when require.js is run, it's really mostly used when you have to define dependencies before you load require.js.

this is what your structure should look like

```
//config.js
require.config({
    paths: {
        libs: "../assets/js/libs",
        plugins: "../assets/js/plugins",
        jquery: "../assets/js/libs/jquery",
        underscore: "../assets/js/libs/underscore",
        backbone: "../assets/js/libs/backbone",
        marionette: "../assets/js/libs/backbone.marionette"
    }
});

require(['app']);

//app.js
define(
    [ "jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette" ],
    function ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette ) {
        //....
    }
);

//app.view.js
define(
    [ "jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette", "app" ], 
    function ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette, App ) {
        //....
    }
);

//app.route.js 
define(
    [ "backbone", "app" ], 
    function ( Backbone, App ) {
        //....
    }
);
```

Bear in mind that all your libraries and modules need to be AMD compliant and if you want to use app as a path like in app.view.js then you need to define it as one. The same with egis, because you can't load modules like so [ "Backbone", "App" ] if they are not defined in require.config as paths.

Comment: Ok I get that. But the problem is, how do I let RequireJS know about app.view.js and app.route.js? At the moment the system knows about app because of the require(['app']) but nothing knows about the app.view.js and app.route.js and hence they don't get loaded, only app gets loaded.

Comment: anything that you want to load you need to require or define. So you do just the same with app.view.js and app.route.js. The usual pattern is that you initialise all that you need to start your app in app.js. So in app.js you require it in your define statement and then create a new instance of what you defined in those like this `define(['app.route.js', 'app.view.js'], function(appRoute, appView){ var route = new appRoute(); var mainView = new appView(); }`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I startup:

```
// main.js
define(["jquery", "app", "router"], function ($, App) {
  "use strict";
  // domReady plugin maybe best used here?
  $(function() {
    App.start();
  });
});

// app.js
define(["backbone", "marionette"], function (Backbone) {
  "use strict";
  var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
  app.on("initialize:after", function(options){
    if (Backbone.history){
      Backbone.history.start();
    }
  });

  return app;
});

// router.js
define(["backbone", "controller", "marionette"], function(Backbone, controller) {
  "use strict";
  var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        "": "index"
    }
  });
  return new Router({
    controller: controller
  });
});

// controller.js
define(["view"], function(View) {
  return {
    "index": {
      new View(); // Do what you like here…
    }
  }
});

// view.js
define(["backbone"], function(Backbone) {
  // view here
});
```

I assume that the dependency to router.js could be put on app.js but basically the call to Backbone.history.start() needs routers to be loaded. 
The router has a dependency on the controller. It's the controller that has all the dependencies to the views etc that is used by it. There could be models and collections etc.

Hope that helps.